# userDefaults.setObject crashes on device but not in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am having trouble with an application. It runs in the simulator, but it crashes on start in a real device. 
The code is quite simple:

```
class loginScreen: UIViewController {

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userDefaults.setObject("127.0.0.1", forKey: "host")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

I tested this on an iOS 7 and iOS 8 simulator without problems but when executed on a real device it crashes on the 
`userDefaults.setObject("127.0.0.1", forKey: "host")` line and I don't really know why. 
In the debugger console I have no messages (except an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in the setObject line when it crashes) and in the iPhone crash logs I can read:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffffc
```

I can't understand why a so different behavior between two "systems"..

Of course I tried a lot of suggestions like:

- placing and `userDefaults.synchronize()` before setObject method
- declare an NSString variable with value "127.0.0.1" and use it in the setObject method
- use setValue instead setObject
- use a different type ( `userDefaults.setObject(666, forKey: "host")` )

but nothing changes, it always crashes when it tries to set a value to userDefaults...any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

PS: commenting `userDefaults.setObject("127.0.0.1", forKey: "host")` and `userDefaults.synchronize()` app starts without problems

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the problem is with user defaults, try commenting the last two line and run the app and see if it still crashes, if it does then its something relevant with your view setup

Comment: sorry..my fault..I forgot to list this in my "tries"..anyway yes, without those lines app runs without problems so I'm pretty sure that problems is in userDefaults..but I can't understand why only on a real device..(I edit my post adding this try)

Comment: Did you make sure to delete any previous versions of the app on your phone before you tried this?

Comment: Honestly..no..I mean, I click "play" button in XCode but I've never deleted it directly from the phone before trying it...I will try and I will let you know..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that making a project clean and reinstall it on the device solved the problem. Thanks all for replies!